# How do you bypass the google account on an RCA RCT6873W42 Android 6.0 tablet?

Tags: factory-reset, tablet

I factory reset my tablet, but before I did the reset I went into settings and turned off backup and reset. So when I did the reset I pressed wipe data/factory reset then it said am I sure I want to do this it had two options yes or no and I pressed yes. So now it's saying enter the last account that was synced but I cant because I turned it off.

Can someone help me get bypassed the google account set up so i can just get on my tablet? I've tried everything nothing seems to be working. I even called tech support but they're closed.

Comment: its an RCA RCT6873W42-ANDROID6.0 Tablet

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Have you already checked with our [factory-reset tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info) and followed up the relevant links? Did they not help?

Answer (score 0):

> So now it's saying enter the last account that was synced but I cant because I turned it off.

You need to remove all accounts before you factory reset! Just enter the last account used on the device to start again.

- It's locked to the last account for security reasons ( Eg.  stolen and hard reset devices )
- You'll need to type the exact credentials that you last used on the device to unlock it
- Sync settings have nothing to do with the extra device security features